# Fonts not found on texlive installation on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: fonts, amsfonts

I took some style files along with a certain .fts file containing a list of fonts from a person to give format to my own tex file. However, The tex file I made is not running on Ubuntu 16.04, although it is running fine on Ubuntu 12.04. The file manages to run, although with a lot of warnings, if I comment this .fts file.

This .fts file contains a list of fonts like rptmb, rptmr, rphvr, etc. Following is a portion of the file in question.

```
\font\fivbf=rptmb at 6.0pt 
\font\sixbf=rptmb at 6.8pt
\font\sevbf=rptmb at 7.6pt 
\font\egtbf=rptmb at 8.4pt 
%\font\ninbf=rptmb at 9.2pt
\font\tenbf=rptmb at 10.0pt
\font\elvbf=rptmb at 10.8pt
\font\twlbf=rptmb at 11.6pt
\font\frtnbf=rptmb at 13.2pt
\font\svtnbf=rptmb at 15.6pt
\font\twtybf=rptmb at 18.0pt
\font\twfvbf=rptmb at 22.0pt
```

There is also a section in this file commented as AMS Fonts. Please help. Is it possible, that some fonts or settings that were available on earlier versions of Texlive are not available on the newer ones? What would be the remedy?

Comment: They're in the `cspsfonts` package. Use `tlmgr` to install them.

Comment: I can use such a font with miktex, so with some digging one could find the relevant files, but imho it is not worth the trouble. That's a bad way to load the fonts. You should better repair the document.